# Why are there two build.gradle files in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After having imported an Eclipse project into Android Studio, I see two `build.gradle` files:

```
1 - <PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle
2 - <PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle
```

The first version is shorter, the second version contains definitions for `compileSdkVersion`, etc.

What is the purpose behind having two separate files?  Are there separate build tasks?

Comment: Similar question to [Difference between build.gradle(Project) and build.gradle(Module)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295933/difference-between-build-gradleproject-and-build-gradlemodule)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle` is specific for **app module**.

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` is a **"Top-level build file"** where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

If you use another module in your project, as a local library you would have another `build.gradle` file:
`<PROJECT_ROOT>\module\build.gradle`

For **example** in your top level file you can specify these common properties:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
}
```

In your `app\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, will accept your answer momentarily.  Is the `build.gradle` file's presence mandatory to trigger a build?  Also, does the top level build file call sub-level files? (Although there is no evidence of that.)

Comment: The build.gradle files are mandatory if you want to build a project with gradle. Android Studio doesn't require gradle, but it is highly recommended. The top level file doesn't call sub files; gradle works with tasks, but it is difficult to explain in a comment.

Comment: Thanks so much Gabriele, this will get me started.

Comment: Especially the `rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion` construct is very informative.

Comment: Is it important to take the detour using ext{...} or should we directly apply the android plugin and the compileSdkVersion to the top-level build file?

Comment: So if you are using Facebook SDK, then I would use top-level build.gradle

Comment: I've sometime seen the same dependancy classpath directed to be put in project build or app build depending on doc, for instance SMR's answer below directs dependancies in both gradles. Is there any reason to put a dependancy classpath in the app build gradle if it's already in the project build gradle?

Comment: @Androidcoder if there are multiple modules and for example you want to use a plugin only in 1 module you can put it inside the module/build.gradle file.

Answer (score 31):

From the official documentation:

> Android Studio projects contain a top-level project Gradle build file that allows you to add the configuration options common to all application modules in the project. Each application module also has its own `build.gradle` file for build settings specific to that module.

[image]

### Project Build File

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` or the **Project Build File** is for the **entire project**, so it will be used for global project configurations.
A typical **Project Build File** contains the following:

- buildscript which defines:

  - repositories and
  - dependencies
- Gradle Plugin version

> By default, the project-level Gradle file uses *buildscript* to define the Gradle *repositories* and *dependencies*. This allows different projects to use different Gradle versions. Supported repositories include JCenter, Maven Central, or Ivy. This example declares that the build script uses the JCenter repository and a classpath dependency artifact that contains the Android plugin for Gradle version 1.0.1.

---

### Module Build File

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle` or the **Module Build File** is for a **specific module** so it will be used for specific module level configurations.
A **Module Build File** contains the following:

> - android settings
> - compileSdkVersion
> - buildToolsVersion
> - defaultConfig and productFlavors
>
>   - manifest properties such as applicationId, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and test information
> - buildTypes
>
>   - build properties such as debuggable, ProGuard enabling, debug signing, version name suffix and testinformation
> - dependencies

You can read the official documentation here:

[Projects and modules build settings](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html#projectModules)