# Gradle Sync Error:(57,0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, actionbarsherlock

[image: the pathways]I'm having a lot of trouble moving source code from github to Android Studio and I think a big part of the problem is with the gradle build tool files. I have never worked with android studio before and don't have a whole lot of coding experience in general. The gradle sync error I'm getting right now is

```
Error:(57,0) Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

I feel like part of the problem might be the way in which i added the actionbarsherlock library. I had to add a lot of folders and so my pathways might be causing problems. Is that a possibility? I can include screenshots if that may be more helpful.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':library')
}

android {

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

buildTypes {
    debug{
        debuggable = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your gradle file here

Comment: which one? I have multiple build.gradle files

Comment: your build.gradle in app module.

Comment: I have edited my post to have the exact source code file from github

Comment: where have you placed the library projects? It cannot  find it in the path.

Comment: i added the libraries as modules

Comment: this might help you solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508777/gradle-error-in-android-studio-plugin-with-id-com-android-library-not-found