# Gradle: declaring dependencies in top level build file vs module build file?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

What is the difference in declaring a dependency in a *top level* `build.gradle` file vs a *module's* `build.gradle`?

I see many projects that have dependencies declared in *both* the top level and also within the specific modules.

Which method is seen as *optimal*?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: For example declaring a dependency at the top level (project) build.gradle vs declaring one in a sub module of the project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project

Comment: @java123999, you have repeated the question. I'm asking for `build.gradle` examples.

Comment: What I want to know is why should dependencies be declared in the module level build files rather than declaring them all at the top level (project) build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had a dependency which was required by ALL subprojects I would declare it at the top level.  For example all subprojects probably use junit, so I would put that at in the build.gradle for the top level project.  If a dependency only related to one particular subproject it would be better to only declare the dependency in that project, since this would prevent it from being pulled in to other subprojects that dont require the dependency.

Comment: Ok I understand this now, is this due to memory space?

Comment: Its really just because its inefficient to package a lot of additional dependencies with code unless they're needed.  It will slow down your build, and cause various other annoying problems.

Comment: Yeah so if a dependency is declared at top level it will be downloaded for each sub module? if this was the case would it override an older version of the dependency in the module build.gradle? Thanks, this is very helpful for me as a gradle newbie!