# Android Studio. Error:(19,0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Got the problem after updating Android Studio, SDK and tools:

> Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Please help to fix it:

Top **build.gradle** file:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
   // buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' //23.02.2
}
dependencies {
}
```

The other one ***build.gradle*** (Module:app)file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mateuyabar.android.pillownfc"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

**Here is the Error Messages Gradle Sync:**

> Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Possible causes:

The project 'pillowNFC-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
-Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
-Apply Gradle plugin

**Event Log:**

11:20:46 Gradle sync started

11:20:48 Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

**I know, this problem was asked before, but I didn't find solution in anothe discussions =(**

It would be nice if somebody can help, I'm quite new in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `build.gradle` file

In your **top-level** file **you can't use** the `android` block.
Check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project/23241888#23241888).

**Just remove this part from the first build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
   // buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' //23.02.2
}
dependencies {
}
```

Also pay attention.
**Since you are using the appcompat v23**, y**ou have to compile with API 23**.

In your `module/build.gradle`  change the `compileSdkVersion` to **23**

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. I forgot, that latest version is 23.

Comment: Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.