# getting issues while adding other gradle project as library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization, jitpack

actually i have been trying to import  another gradle project as library from github and i know that there are two ways to do that

1)by adding url to dependencies in build.gradle file
this method gave lot of errors

2)manually download library and import it as module, then add dependencies

and i somehow succeeded by using second method ..

after that gradle sync worked correctly but while running application it gives some bizzare errors like

Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ompile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'AppIntro' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

and the github link is  as follows

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

i imported folder called as library in that....

Comment: looks like you (or someone else) misspelled `compile()` as `ompile()` ...

Comment: how do i change it and don't know where it is , because it in imported library @Shark

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` file... just it's `dependencies` block. maybe you misspelled it as `ompile 'https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro'`

Comment: sorry and yes... it was misspelled and i corrected it... i never thought error is in my .gradle file ..as it suggested error in AppIntro Library...thanks for the time and sorry for such feeble doubt..

Comment: no, it merely *said* that there is no `ompile()` method, and *suggested* that the AppIntro may be using a newer version of Gradle which no longer contains that method and told you to open the Gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this library in many ways:

- Add a simple dependency in your `build.gradle` file

Just use:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
}
```

- Use the [**jitpack** plugin](https://jitpack.io/)

Just add this repo to your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

And the dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

- download the module (the library folder) locally.

Comment: much obliged ......but i have very layman's doubt,there are two build.grade files what's the difference between each other...

Comment: @viru For other question I suggest you asking a new question. In this way other users can help you resolving your doubts. In any case. Each module has a build.gradle file, and there is a top-level build.gradle file. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project/23241888#23241888