# Could not find support-v4.aar(com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

The project is one of Google samples on Github, [Androidtv-Leanback](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback).  I cloned it and opened with Android studio, but build fails.

Error:

> Could not find support-v4.aar(com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1)

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.tvleanback"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recommendation:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:24.1.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8'
//    compile files('src/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this dependency in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
...
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1"
}
```

and make sure you have downloaded the android support repository using sdk manager.

Comment: I do  it as you say,but now  saying `Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.jar`

Comment: add the dependency in your app\build.gradle file. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23241888/5545429

Comment: I resolved the it by changing all the sdk version to from 24.1.1to 24.2.1.And thanks a lot !