# Android Studio: Gradle Build Unit Testing dependencies issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I am a novice to Android development. I am looking into 'how to set up a test environment in Android Studio'. So, here is my question;

As per the official Android training source (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) says, In your app's top-level *build.gradle* file, you need to specify these libraries as dependencies:

[image]

But in my case, am using Android Studio Version 2.2.3 and it shows two *build.gradle* files i.e., *build.gradle ( Project: name )* and *build.gradle ( Module: app )*, out of which one already had the dependencies mentioned by default and the other doesn't. Please look at following pictures for understanding.

**build.gradle ( Project: name )**
[image]

**build.gradle ( Module: app )**
[image]

**Where should the dependencies be mentioned?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there two build.gradle files in an Android Studio project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: My question is not specifically about why but where the dependencies to be mentioned.

Comment: Place them in your app build.gradle (second screenshot)

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Thank you for the response. But it shows the dependency by default regards Junit. So, no more edit required in setting up new android projects. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, junit dependency is added by default. But mockito is not

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Just curious to know what's the difference with Project and Module in this scenario. Could you please state with a practical example? Isn't it better to have dependencies in Project Gradle build file as when we hit Run, it does unit testing for all classes in entire project?