# Error:(9, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1]

Tags: android, reactive-programming

When I sync my android studio project it get
Error:(9, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

My build.gradle file is below

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call this library in the wrong section. There are two kinds of `build.gradle` files. For more information **[build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)**

In order to solve the problem, you should add required dependencies into  `build.gradle` in the module level, to be exact **app\build.gradle**

Remove your **dependencies** from root '`build.gradle' and paste them in **app\build.gradle**.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion // YOURS
    buildToolsVersion // YOURS
    ...........
        }
    dependencies {
            compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
            compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
    }
```

**FYI**

It's better to use the latest version,

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
```

Comment: When I add this in build.gradle Module Level it gets error         Failed to resolve: io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9

Comment: Error(29,13) and Error(28,13) : Disable offline mode and Sync show in file show in project structure dialog

Comment: @DipuKumar click `Disable offline mode and Sync show` and gradle