# How to add custom dependencies automatically in android for any new project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If I use these libraries usually, I want a way to include them in any  project I create.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
 implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'
```

**What should I do?**

Comment: you may try to make a gradle as a module and import it if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find your **[App level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)** (In which you can add your dependencies as shown below) Gradle template

**Go to**

> **android-studio-path\plugins\android\lib\templates\eclipse\projects\NewAndroidApplication\root\build.gradle.ftl**

And edit **build.gradle.ftl** like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
<#if mavenUrl == "mavenCentral">
        mavenCentral()
<#else>
        maven { url '${mavenUrl}' }
</#if>
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:${gradlePluginVersion}'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
<#if mavenUrl == "mavenCentral">
    mavenCentral()
<#else>
    maven { url '${mavenUrl}' }
</#if>
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion ${buildApi}
    buildToolsVersion "${buildToolsVersion}"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion ${minApi}
        targetSdkVersion ${targetApi}
    }
}

dependencies {   /// ADD YOUR DEPENDENDENCIES HERE
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:${v4SupportLibraryVersion}'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1' //add your dependancies here
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' 
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
<#if mavenUrl != "mavenCentral">
        maven {
            url '${mavenUrl}'
        }
</#if>
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

For your **[Project level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)** Gradle template go to

> **android-studio-path\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root\build.gradle.ftl**

---

> ***Note***:
>
> 1. My android-studio-path is **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio**. Replace with your own
> 2. Before doing this make a backup of `build.gradle.ftl` file.

### Edit

If you are facing **[access denied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoZ9GvRVqmo)** problem then grant your editor administrative privileges. In windows type your editor (eg. Notepad) name in the search box and right click and select run as Administrator. And then

> File=>open=>above file

---

If you're facing again you must close android studio and try again. It should work.

**See Gradle [documentation of dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)**

And you can customise much more in **template** folder.

Comment: This path to the Top-level build file 
where exactly can i put my dependencies?

Comment: I have added your dependencies check it @MohamedAdelraZek

Comment: When i try to save the file, it tells my Access denied

Comment: if you are using windows then search notepad in the search bar and right-click on it and click on run as administrator and open file on that editor, like file open =>build.gradle.ftl @MohamedAdelraZek