# change in build.gradle to sync gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm new to android.
I build a new project in android studio, but I can not sync the gradle.
I've searched and there were some recommendations which said the solution is making changes in module/build.gradle
I found two build.gradle but I don't know which one is module/build.gradle, however I did make change to both of them.(I added android method)
[the first grdle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kVHc.png)

[second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmWO8.png)

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

The tab you're looking is Project. It's like a File Explorer.
It says Project change it to Android from drop down menu.

That tab will have only the necessary files. There you will find both the Project gradle and module gradle.

The thing is you can find those files in Project also but it's easy and more convenient to work in Android Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You not necessarily need to make changes to build.gradle in order to run a Gradle sync task. Let me first answer your first question:

### I don't know which one is module build.gradle

When you crate a new Android studio project there are two build.gradle files you see. One in MyAppliaction/build.gradle and other is app/build.gradle.

Here MyAppliaction/build.gradle is the Project gradle file which is also called global gradle where you can configure project wide golbal configurations. As per your screenshot you have added depandencies{} in project build.gradle which is not correct(that's why your gradle sync is failed!), you can add depandencies object only in module build.gradle.

app/build.gradle is the "module" gradle file where you can configure module specific configs and dependencies. Module build.gradle will at least one for each module if you create one more library module in your project, that will have separate build.gradle.

### but I can not sync the gradle

Yes, when you make any change to project or module build.gradle, you get a "Sync" button on top which can start gradle sync. But if you want gradle sync anytime just open on "Gradle" tab from right and click "sync" icon on top left. (see screenshot below)
[image]