# Best practices for build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, project

Currently I am making a few changes in an Android Project and I came across project level build.gradle and app level build.gradle files. However, I can not find any best practises for applying a few plugins I have in mind e.g Spoon plugin etc. 
Do I need to apply the plugins in app level or project level gradle? Are there any best practices and/or performance issues?

Thanks in advance for your answers!!

Comment: Read this [App level gradle vs project level gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already read this thread. Unfortunately, I can't find what is the best practice for plugins. From what I understand if I apply a plugin in Project level gradle, it will be visible in all modules and if I apply a plugin in app level gradle, it will be visible to this specific module. However, I can't find any best practices, if there are any...