# Gradle failed to fetch dependencies

Tags: gradle, admob, fetch

I get this error when gradle try to fetch dependencies.

> Failed to run 'D:\Unity Projects\Floppy
>   Eagle\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b "D:\Unity
>   Projects\Floppy
>   Eagle\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle"
>   --no-daemon "-PANDROID_HOME=F:/sdk" "-PTARGET_DIR=D:\Unity Projects\Floppy Eagle\Assets\Plugins\Android"
>   "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com"
>   "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0"'
>   stdout: Unzipping
>   C:\Users\LeapTech.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju\gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip
>   to
>   C:\Users\LeapTech.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju

Comment: Paste your gradle file.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Sorry I don't know where is located gradle file

Comment: @AbidullahKhan check this to find them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project

Comment: This is unity project not android studio project

Comment: Search for *.gradle in your project files. You probably added an invalid version. try 15.0.1 for the ads dependency, that's the current one.

Comment: @AbidullahKhan where you see unity project? scroll down in answer and check where is gradle files and post in your question so we can help you