# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0]

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am unable to run my app in the android emulator.  It was working previously, but something broke it.

Error message:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I am running gradle 3.2.1. Here is my build.gradle file's buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the top-level gradle file.

Move this line to the dependencies section of the `build.gradle` file inside the app folder, and also update to latest version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
```

For more info, see here: [Why are there two build.gradle files in an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: Also it should be `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01`.

Answer (score 0):

Write that line in build.gradle(Module:yourAppName.app)file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).