# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'Android()'

Tags: java, android, gradle, methods, dsl

I tried all three solutions no one of them solved the problem .
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'Android()'
Possible causes:
The project 'hope' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.3 and sync project

The project 'hope' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dot.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }) Android Gradle Plugin
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.12.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

```js
allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}






task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'




        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the words "Android Gradle Plugin" from your upper `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thank you so much .The problem solved :)

Comment: However when I run the app it crashes :( I mean it works and then it close. What could be the reason ?

Comment: E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution may help U:
I`ve added android to build.gradle and there was such a problem, then I removed it and added to app/build.gradle. It work!
In fact I dont know what the differrene  and exact act of this 2 files. But there is!

Comment: that's not an answer but in case you're interested what those files do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241681/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project (the `android` section works in those parts that have the android plugin active, e.g.  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`)